# Altair - highlight single element in bar chart

Tags: python, altair

I have this dagtaframe, talismen_players:

```
                        Team  TotalShots  TotalCreated  Goals  ...  WeightBetweenness  %ShotInv                     Player    Color
0                Aston Villa        55.0          68.0    7.0  ...               0.45      0.36              Jack Grealish  #770038
1            Manchester City        76.0          96.0    8.0  ...               0.44      0.32            Kevin De Bruyne  #97C1E7
2                    Watford        62.0          43.0    4.0  ...               0.37      0.34            Gerard Deulofeu  #FBEE23
3             Leicester City        60.0          67.0    6.0  ...               0.32      0.34             James Maddison  #0053A0
4               Norwich City        29.0          69.0    0.0  ...               0.31      0.32           Emiliano Buendia  #00A14E
5                    Chelsea        63.0          40.0    5.0  ...               0.28      0.23                Mason Mount  #034694
6          Tottenham Hotspur        64.0          30.0    9.0  ...               0.28      0.29              Son Heung-Min  #132257
7                    Everton        66.0          30.0   10.0  ...               0.22      0.26                Richarlison  #274488
8                    Arsenal        64.0          18.0   17.0  ...               0.21      0.27  Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang  #EF0107
9                Bournemouth        25.0          40.0    1.0  ...               0.21      0.23                Ryan Fraser  #D3151B
10            Crystal Palace        42.0          20.0    6.0  ...               0.20      0.24                Jordan Ayew  #C4122E
11                   Burnley        33.0          40.0    2.0  ...               0.20      0.27              Dwight McNeil  #630F33
12          Newcastle United        41.0          24.0    1.0  ...               0.20      0.24                  Joelinton  #231F20
13                 Liverpool        89.0          41.0   14.0  ...               0.18      0.31              Mohamed Salah  #CE1317
14  Brighton and Hove Albion        27.0          52.0    2.0  ...               0.16      0.23                Pascal Groß  #005DAA
15   Wolverhampton Wanderers        86.0          38.0   11.0  ...               0.16      0.38               Raul Jimenez  #FDB913
16          Sheffield United        31.0          35.0    5.0  ...               0.15      0.24                 John Fleck  #E52126
17           West Ham United        48.0          18.0    6.0  ...               0.15      0.25           Sebastien Haller  #7C2C3B
18               Southampton        64.0          21.0   15.0  ...               0.11      0.24                 Danny Ings  #ED1A3B
19         Manchester United        37.0          31.0    1.0  ...               0.10      0.17            Andreas Pereira  #E80909
```

And I have singled out one element in a series being plotted by `altair`, like so:

```
    target_team = 'Liverpool'
    # the following prints 'Mohamed Salah'
    target_player = talismen_players.loc[talismen_players['Team']==target_team, 'Player'].item()
    # all elements                
    talisman_chart = alt.Chart(talismen_players).mark_bar().encode(
            alt.Y('Player:N', title="", sort='-x'),
            alt.X('WeightBetweenness:Q', title="Interconectividade do craque com o resto do time"),
            alt.Color('Color', legend=None, scale=None),
            tooltip = [alt.Tooltip('Player:N'),
                       alt.Tooltip('Team:N'),
                       alt.Tooltip('TotalShots:Q'),
                       alt.Tooltip('%ShotInv:Q')],
        ).properties(
        width=800
        ).configure_axis(
        grid=False
        ).configure_view(
        strokeWidth=0
        )
_________
```

This plots all elements, but I want to highlight one of them:

[image]

This is the code for achieving the result using lines: [Multiline highlight](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/multiline_highlight.html)

---

I've tried with this code:

```
highlight = alt.selection(type='single', on='mouseover',
                      fields=['Player'], nearest=True)

base = alt.Chart(talismen_players).encode(
    alt.X('WeightBetweenness:Q'),
    alt.Y('Player:N', title=''),
    alt.Color('Color', legend=None, scale=None),
    tooltip = [alt.Tooltip('Player:N'),
                   alt.Tooltip('Team:N'),
                   alt.Tooltip('TotalShots:Q'),
                   alt.Tooltip('%ShotInv:Q')],
)

points = base.mark_circle().encode(
    opacity=alt.value(0)
).add_selection(
    highlight
).properties(
    width=700
)

lines = base.mark_bar().encode(
    size=alt.condition(~highlight, alt.value(18), alt.value(20))
)
```

But the result is not ideal:

[image]

Highlight is not working.

---

**QUESTION:**

**Ideally, I'd like to have `target_player` bar *highlighted on default*. and THEN be able to highlight the other bars, with mouseover.**

But having `target_player` bar *statically highlighted* suffices.

Highlight should not change bar colors, but rather have a focus quality, while other bars are out of focus.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Do you want a single bar to be statically highlighted, or do you want a dynamic highlight based on the position of the mouse? It would help if you could include a full [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your chart, as the images you show do not seem to match the code you've included.

Comment: I want a bar statically highlighted, on default.

Comment: I've edited the question. Ideally, I'd like to have a bar highlighted on default, with target_player. and THEN be able to highlight the other bars, with mouseover. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Also I've removed the graph that is not being reproduced by my code.

Comment: Your code is still unclear: you show a chart with `mark_circle()`, but then the result is a bar graph. Are the circles part of your question, or not? Additionally, you never defined your `talismen_players` data. It's difficult to reproduce your charts without access to the data they represent.

Comment: This very code is what is plotting the graphs, however, with `mark_circle()`. Maybe thats why it is failing to work. I've edited the question, adding the dataframe. Hope this helps

Comment: Where are the circles? Every image you include is a bar graph. Regarding the dataframe: a formatted printout is of very little help. What code do I run to reproduce your chart?

Comment: the example was taken from this link (https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/multiline_highlight.html), where `mark_circle()` is used and there are no circles either.

Comment: how can I pass you the dataframe in a better format? please let me how how I could help you. All you need to reproduce is here.

Comment: It's better to provide your dataframe in the form of code; see my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using an initialized selection, along with an opacity for highlighting. For example:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'y': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'color': ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
})

hover = alt.selection_single(fields=['y'], on='mouseover', nearest=True, init={'y': 'C'})

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    color='color',
    opacity=alt.condition(hover, alt.value(1.0), alt.value(0.3))
).add_selection(hover)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, how do I make `scale=None`?. I need to preserve custom colors.

Comment: To provide custom colors, set ``scale=None`` on the color encoding.

Comment: set as `alt.Color('Color', legend=None, scale=None)`?